# Error while running React project with "npm start"

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm attempting to run my React project using the `npm start` command. However, I am seeing an error message, despite the fact that the `scripts` section in my `package.json` file defines "start" as follows:

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

Here's the error I am seeing:

````
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path D:\crwn\crwn-clothing
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\el\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-27T16_51_46_772Z-debug.log```
````

How can I resolve this?

Comment: you need to first run your back-end code. then you need to run front-end by `npm start`. back-end would be `node index` .

Comment: Actually I don't have backend, it is just front and till today it was working well, but all of a sudden I was confronted with this error.

Comment: okay, if so then create a new project in react and try once again